# How to clip this part of mesh in Opengl?

Tags: c++, math, opengl

I tried to clip mesh in openGl and i think that i have a problem with math.
I have a cube [image]

And i need to clip for example half of that cube. So i didn't understand how to calculate this clipping plane. White lines illustrate how this clip plane should looks like, it is just parallel one of the cube sides

My clipping

```
#version 120

varying vec3 ourColor;
varying float clip_distance;
void main()
{
    if ( clip_distance < 0.0 )
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ourColor, 1.0);
}
```

```
#version 120


attribute vec3 aPos;
attribute vec3 aColor;
varying vec3 ourColor;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;


varying float clip_distance;
const vec4 clipPlane = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    
    clip_distance = dot(gl_Position, clipPlane);
    ourColor = aColor;
}
```

So, how to calculate this clipping plane. I want to understand how to calculate clipping planes for each of cube sides

Comment: Read about [User-defined clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#User-defined_clipping).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input vertices describe a (0,0,0) -> (1,1,1) cube, you can solve this with one line at the top of your vertex shader:

```
aPos = clamp(aPos, vec3(clipMinX, clipMinY, clipMinZ),
                   vec3(clipMaxX, clipMaxY, clipMaxZ));
```

where the `clip{Min,Max}*` variables are the axis-aligned distances on which to clip the cube.

For example, `aPos = clamp(aPos, vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,0.5,1))` will cut the top half of the cube.

Comment: I think it won't work because it is not a cube exatly. It is just planes in range (0,0) - (2,2) that i place on the scene with matrix transformations

Comment: I don't know accurate coordinates of each vertices after transformations, so i don't know which clipMinX, clipMinY, clipMinZ and clipMaxX, clipMaxY, clipMaxZ should be

Comment: This is why you put that at the *beginning* of your vertex shader: You clip the vertices of the (0,0,0) -> (2,2,2) cube and the resulting vertices are transformed as usual.

Comment: Okay, I tried explain again. Each side of cube it is Plane(separate mesh, that contains only XY coordinates), I just rotate it and move to get a cube. If I will use your method I just cut incorrect parts of plane. For example:

Comment: Plane (0,0,0) - (2,2,0), rotate it by X on 90° and move it on top of the cube(translate on 2 for example by Y). Now I want to cut all vertices above (0,1,0). Your method do nothing in this situation.

Comment: Ah, you left out that detail in your question. Is the transformation you described part of your `model` transformation or the `view`?

Comment: It is part of model transformation. Each plane has it is own ModelMatrix

Comment: Ah, you left out that detail in your question. If the "rotate the plane and move it" transformation can be separated from the "rotate the entire cube for viewing" transformation, you can do the clipping after multiplying by `model` and before the rest of the vertex transformation. (`view` and `projection`)

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do that, but I lost entire cube after that

Comment: Oh, before  view and projection, okay, I'll try

Comment: It is work, yes, but for that i need to pass cube and place matrix as uniforms separately. Would be clipping is better solution for doing this?

Comment: Just i need to move one of the plane and create a cube behind moving this plane. Like extrude in Blender3D or 3DsMax

Comment: Suggest you ask that as a separate question, I don't see how it has to do with clipping. In fact, it sounds like a gigantic XY problem that probably does not even need clipping a cube.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6VvtW8y9q4&ab_channel=RanjeethMahankali
I want to do something like that. Just i think that OpenGL can do it without a lot of calculation